# Using awk to analyze log file to identify blocks and to extract information

Tags: awk

I am trying to figure out a way to use awk to analyze my log files from an old application. The log file contains processing information from the application but the structure is a bit messy. But it has a structure like this:

```
some random text
...
BLOCK-BEGIN bla bla INFO1:VAL1
variable lines of text
INFO2:VAL2
variable lines of text
POSSIBLE-BLOCK-END-PHRASE1
...
some random text
INFO3:not-desired-val5
...
BLOCK-BEGIN bla bla INFO1:VAL3
variable lines of text
INFO2:VAL4
variable lines of text
POSSIBLE-BLOCK-END-PHRASE2
...
```

What I want to do is to first identify the blocks. In this example above, there are two blocks with same block beginning but different endings. Within each block, I want to extract then few information, i.e. INFO1,INFO2 in the example. The desired output in this case would be:

```
VAL1,VAL2
VAL3,VAL4
```

I know some basic of awk. Therefore, any solutions or hints are highly welcome. Thanks

Update: my first attempt

```
awk '/BLOCK-BEGIN/{printf substr($4,7)",";for (i = 0 ; i < NF; i++) getline; if($0 ~ '/^INFO2/') print substr($0,7)}'
```

The output is:

```
VAL1,VAL2
VAL3,VAL4
```

But is there a better way to do it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, awk is a better tool for this task.

Comment: @mouviciel thanks for your hint. I have tried using awk and but did not get exactly what I want.

Comment: I see you modified your example. How are we supposed to know which INFO strings to print when there's no definite block terminating string, just "possible" block terminating strings? Are we supposed to treat strings like `POSSIBLE-BLOCK-END` as if they ARE block end phrases, or are we supposed to only print 2 INFO strings after every `BLOCK-BEGIN` or something else? Are the `INFO:...` strings always at the end of a line or not (if not show such cases in your input)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '
    (split($NF,a,/:/) == 2) && sub(/^INFO/,"",a[1]) {
        info[a[1]] = a[2]
        if ( a[1] == 2 ) {
            print info[1], info[2]
        }
    }
' file
VAL1,VAL2
VAL3,VAL4
```

Regarding the code you posted in your question:

1. `printf substr($4,7)","` - never do `printf <input data>` as it'll fail when your input contains printf formatting characters, always do `printf "%s", <input data>` instead so that could should be written `printf "%,",substr($4,7)`.
2. `getline` - there's aonly a few specific situations where `getline` is the right approach and when it is you have to write it securely. This isn't the right situation and it's not written securely. See awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.
3. `for (i = 0 ; i < NF; i++)` all field numbers, array indices, and string character positions in awk start at 1, not 0, so write your code to match to you don't trip over thinking arrays or anything else start at zero - `for (i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++)`.
4. `'foo... $0 ~ '/^INFO2/' ...bar'` those inner `'`s are terminating the awk script body and so exposing what's between them to the shell for interpretation. Never do that. In this case idk why you thought you needed them as your code should just be `'foo... $0 ~ /^INFO2/ ...bar'`.

Comment: thanks for your answer and your detailed explanation, and of course for pointing out those mistakes I made. My question is still, why the identifier of the beginning of the block is not used at all? sorry for the basic question.

Comment: Regarding `why the identifier of the beginning of the block is not used at all?` because it's not necessary. According to your example you just want to print pairs of INFO strings.

Comment: thanks Ed! In this case, yes it is not necessary, because I simplified the real-life case for the sake of simplicity. But I afraid I have to stick to process the log block by block, as there might be similar pattern outside of blocks. Those information is something I dont want to have in the result. But, you are right, it is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F'INFO[0-9]+:' '
/BLOCK-BEGIN/{
  if(val2 && val1){
     print val1","val2
  }
  val1=val2=""
  val1=$NF
  next
}
/^INFO[0-9]+:/{
  val2=(val2?val2 ",":"") $NF
}
END{
  if(val2 && val1){
     print val1","val2
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: thanks for your help. It did work with the original example provided earlier. But If there are some text, including something like 'INFO3:val5', outside of the block, it won't work. I will update the example to make it more testable.

Comment: @Orunner, I have updated my answer now, kindly do check it once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: thanks @RavinderSingh13, I tested it and it gives a different output. I got ```VAL1,VAL2,not-desired-val5
VAL3,VAL4
``` and not-desired-val5 was not ignored as it should be.